# c# threads and properties second part

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I have this code:

```
public partial class FrmPrincipal : Form
{
    private Image imagen;

    public FrmPrincipal()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ...
    }

    private void menuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(RequestImage);
        t.Start();
    }

    private void RequestImage()
    {
        try
        {
            ...

            // I want to update this.token
            this.imagen = retrieveImageFromWebService();

            ...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

How can I update image? I want to save a copy of image to update a pictureBox when  user needs it.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem exactly? That code should run fine, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Do you mean, "how can I update token from another thread"?

Comment: @vansfannel - should work fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have there should work fine.  If you are using token in the other thread through, you'll probably want to syncronize gets and sets to avoid data corruption:

```
private string token {
  [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)] get;
  [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)] set;
}
```

This syncronization method is [not 100% safe in all circumstances](http://www.ddj.com/windows/184406245;jsessionid=5ECUPWMHDQV2CQSNDLOSKHSCJUNN2JVN?_requestid=8098), but for your purposes it should work

Comment: That ends up locking on "this" which is generally a bad idea. IMO it's better to lock on an explicit, private lock.

Comment: Jon makes a good point of course - I was going for the simplest solution here, but using a separate lock is the best practice

Answer (score 2):

Your code will work perfectly well is it is. However, if you want to read the value from another thread and make sure you always get the most recent value, you should either make it volatile or acquire a lock each time you read or write it.

See [the memory model section of my threading article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/volatility.shtml) for more information.